# Reading actions back so as to intentionally make them appear fundamentally evil?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Looking for a word: essentially, it should be a noun.  Described as: turning well-intended actions into ill-intended actions in rhetoric (i.e., by committing intentional fallacies or disrupting the counterpart).  Possible definition: "the process by which descriptions of actions are turned into accusations".  Also, a good synonym?

### Let's look at an example, then:

I think you're really good at '~ion'--painting things in a positive light, or at least remaining optimistic.  It's the opposite of '~ion', whereby people turn my past against me, or insist on pessimism.

### Possible:

Reticence or interdiction; veto or blackballing; repudiation, rejection, or derision; counfouding, contrition, or impeding?

### Update

I'm really looking for an utterance that encompasses the initial state of neutrality or even goodness.  While demonizing and vilification fit, I'm hesitant to concede that they imply a full transformation, exclusively in delusion, from good to evil.  I'm trying to put a word to this thing I've noticed that so many people seem to do: it's the opposite of coping: it's some mechanism of hysteria or obstruction/disruption--some kind of mayhem.  It's important to me that I be able to find a concise, descriptive phrase (it doesn't need to be a single word).

### Update 2

I went with `swaying`, from Robert Frost's 'The Sound of Trees'.  I think it captures the essence of what I'm looking for and encapsulates everything else mentioned.  I was basically seeking a hyponym for the other words listed that had to do with people throwing off their responsibilities, if even by turning negative to positive.  If anyone has other terms that are more widely known, please update your answers or add a new answer.  Thank you.

Comment: I think you might need to add an example. Sort of like _Why don't you put the children to sleep?_ but when read with an evil intention it sounds like you mean infanticide ?

Comment: @Frank More like, after you put the kids to sleep, you're thinking, {accomplished} "Great, I finally got them to sleep!"  But your spouse says {hurt/angry} "You put the children to sleep!"  Essentially, everything becomes an accusation.

Comment: I like the other words I have seen in this thread better, but I did want to give you one simple, accurate response: demonizing.  de·mon·ize
ˈdēməˌnīz/
verb


    portray as wicked and threatening.
    "seeking to demonize one side in the conflict"

Comment: @APrejean It's great, but ..., what about an antonym?

Comment: can·on·ize
[kan-uh-nahyz]  Just because it makes you think of the church, doesn't mean that is its only usage: 2.
to glorify.

Comment: I've heard this mentioned in media, popular fiction, and journalism, so many times over.  I think it would be very useful to have an easy-to-remember term that everyone could easily agree upon.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer to your question is **perversion**.

> the process of affecting something good or right in a negative way so
>   that it becomes something bad or wrong

But I also think the general term **distortion** (or twist) works here too but it can go both ways.

> the action of giving a misleading account or impression.

Answer (score 0):

...  vilify ... I guess ... you need context to say that .. heheh

Don't vilify me! Your compassion is revolting. I would rather you say so much as doing.

Comment: Right, well vilification because we're looking for a noun.  Interesting choice.  Very interesting choice.  I'm wondering if this is a good choice even for inanimate and abstract objects....  Hmm....

Comment: Agreed that you should edit it to make it a noun.

Answer (score 0):

Someone can *put the worst possible construction* on your action, *see it in a negative light* or *intentionally misinterpret* it. They can also *set you up to fail* or *frame* you. They can *denigrate, slander, smear, badmouth, defame* and *libel* you. They can also *project their failures / faults / shortcomings* onto you, as well as *{see / look for} evil where there is none*.

Comment: Yeah.  Take all that, clump it together into one word, and what do you get?  Basically, 'doing anything possible to create a negative relationship and interpret things poorly'....

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider "**diabolization**" and "**denigration**."

> [**diabolize**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diabolize): to represent as or make diabolical.
>
> [**denigrate**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/denigrate): to treat or represent as lacking in value or importance,; belittle; disparage -- *also:* to make black; blacken.